# Thesis formatting - ToC, figure

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

This question has been updated. See - [Adding label in list of figures and tables, removing dot from ToC, notation in a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563049/adding-label-in-list-of-figures-and-tables-removing-dot-from-toc-notation-in-a)

Comment: In addition to the request to have one question per post, it's helpful if you can trim your example down.  Most of the packages you've loaded are not related to how your TOC formats nor how cross references display.  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/107497

Answer (score 1):

The regular procedure on this site is to ask one question at a time, but you have asked four. I can answer three of them but can't be bothered with your fourth. Ask another question about it.--- GOM

```
% thesisprob.tex  SE 562876
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3\baselineskip} % change space before chapter titles

\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Fig. }  % put before figure entries
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5em} % extra space for Fig. number
% and similar for tables

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{First}
\begin{figure}
\centering
AN ILLUSTRATION
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Second}
\begin{figure}
\centering
AN ILLUSTRATION
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful. I appreciate Your effort.