# Adding label in list of figures and tables, removing dot from ToC, notation in a subfigure

Tags: table-of-contents, subfloats

I am having some problem with my thesis format. Please help me to fix these issues. thanks in advance

1. How to add figure label in subfigure. Currently it's showing as **a) caption.....** but I want it as **Fig. 2.1(a) caption....**
2. I want to get **Fig. 1.1 example figure** instead of **1.1 example figure** in List of Figures. I can't use `tocloft` package. I have tested it. It's not working because of the `titlesec and titletoc`. I have used both of these packages extensively in my format.
3. I want the same for List of Tables. Now it comes as **2.1 abc**. But I need **Table 2.1 abc**
4. Is there any way to cite the figure and table as bold face without typing `\textit{...}` everytime -

for example in page 6 it comes like this “Fig. 2.1” shows an example image. But I need **“Fig. 2.1”**
shows an example image.

5. I need to remove the dots from the ToC

an working mwe is given here. complete format can be found here - [Thesis formatting - ToC, figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562876/thesis-formatting-toc-figure)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}


\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc} 


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables



\setstretch{1.5}
\chapter{SIMULATION}
\section{Example section}
\lipsum[2-3]

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{SIMULATION2}
\section{Example section 2}


\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Example figure 2.1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{Example figure 2.2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Example figure 2}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

``Fig.~\ref{fig2}'' shows an example image.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I implemented all your requirements. It's recommended to ask for one thing in one question.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}


\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, labelsep=space, belowskip=-5pt, aboveskip=10pt]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{xpatch}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}


\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\thefigure~(\alph{subfigure})}
\renewcommand\thesubtable{\thetable~(\alph{subtable})}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@figure{Fig.~}
\renewcommand\p@subfigure{Fig.~}
\renewcommand\p@table{Table.~}
\renewcommand\p@subtable{Table.~}
\makeatother

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{subfigure-label}{Fig.~#2}
\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{subtable-label}{Table.~#2}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{figurelist}{#1#2}
\DeclareCaptionListFormat{tablelist}{#1#2}

\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=subfigure-label}
\captionsetup[subtable]{labelformat=subtable-label}
\captionsetup[figure]{listformat=figurelist}
\captionsetup[table]{listformat=tablelist}

% dotless toc entries
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd\@dottedtocline
  {\leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern\@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern\@dotsep mu$}}
  {}
  {}{\fail}

% enlarge label width
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{4em}}
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{5em}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{figure}{}{}
\crefname{table}{}{}
\creflabelformat{figure}{#2\textbf{#1}#3}
\creflabelformat{table}{#2\textbf{#1}#3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables



%\setstretch{1.5}
\chapter{SIMULATION}
\section{Example section}
%\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Example figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{SIMULATION2}
\section{Example section 2}

\begin{table}
  \caption{text}\label{tab1}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Example figure 2.1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \caption{Example figure 2.2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Example figure 2}
    \label{fig2}
\end{figure}

``\cref{fig2}'' shows an example image.5

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't express how much grateful I am. May the creator bless You. Everything is working perfectly. However I have a small problem - In Toc subsection and subsubsection is still showing the dots

Comment: @MAzharulIslam Updated. Now `xpatch` package is loaded and the code for dotless toc entries is changed.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks for Your great effort and for the time You have given to solve this.